# Windows Service keeps starting and stopping

Tags: c#, windows-services

Kept on encountering this error message when starting my Windows Service.

The service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services and programs.

My codes:

```
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
     {
        string eventLogMessage = string.Format(@"Notify Service is starting :{0}", DateTime.Now);
        EventLogging.LogInformation(eventLogMessage);

            double interval;

            try
            {
                interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["intervalInSeconds"]);
                EventLogging.LogInformation(
                    string.Format("Loaded configuration: Interval duration is {0} minutes", (interval / 60)));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                interval = 3600;

                eventLogMessage = string.Format("Loading configuration failed: Interval duration is {0} minutes", (interval / 60));
                eventLogMessage += string.Format("\nMessage was: {0}", exception.Message);

                EventLogging.LogWarning(eventLogMessage);
            }

            interval = interval * 1000;

            _timer.Interval = interval;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
            _timer.Start();

            eventLogMessage = string.Format(@"Notify service has started: {0}", DateTime.Now);
            EventLogging.LogInformation(eventLogMessage);

            var workerThread = new Thread(NotifyUsers) { IsBackground = true };
            workerThread.Start();

    }

    private void NotifyUsers()
    {
        var userBL = new UserBL();

        List<User> usersToBeMailed = userBL.GetAllUsersWhosePasswordsWillExpire();

        string eventLogMessage = string.Format("Number of users to be mailed is {0}", usersToBeMailed.Count);
        EventLogging.LogInformation(eventLogMessage);

        foreach (User user in usersToBeMailed)
        {
            userBL.MailUser(user);
        }
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var workerThread = new Thread(NotifyUsers) { IsBackground = true };
        workerThread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        string eventLogMessage = @"Password notify service has stopped: " + DateTime.Now;

        EventLogging.LogInformation(eventLogMessage);
    }


    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        _timer.Stop();
        EventLogging.LogWarning("Paused");
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        base.OnContinue();
        _timer.Start();
        EventLogging.LogInformation("Resumed");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are fairly strict rules on what can go in the `OnStart`\`OnStop` methods.  I'm guessing the `workerThread` code.  As a test try removing that and see if it still stops.

Comment: Also move the _timer and the worker to a separate 'initialization' method.  The `OnStart` should be simple with full exception handling.

Comment: Try attaching the debugger to the service to find where the exception is happening, add a Thread.Sleep(30000) at the first line of the the OnStart() method so you could have sometime to attach the debugger before the code completes executing. Don't forget a breakpoint after the Thread.Sleep call, so you could manually debug line by line when the thread is awake.

Comment: You may find some useful information in the windows logs. Open MMC on Event Viewer, navigate to Windows Logs->Application. Usually you find some thrown exception there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have at least one of *your* threads doing something and not being a background thread, to keep the process alive. The thread that the `OnStart` code runs on isn't really one of your threads, and besides, you have to return from `OnStart` in order to be considered to have successfully started.

This could be as simple as creating and running a new `Thread` from your `OnStart` method that just waits on a `ManualResetEvent` object that you `Set` from your `OnStop` code.

Alternatively, find some useful work for this thread to do (but still use the event object to signal when it should shut down), or alternative two is - consider whether this code belongs in a service at all. If it's just waking periodically to notify users, why not use a scheduled task instead?